# Why in elisp function only the first print is displayed

Tags: print

I have the code below:

```
(defun double-print ()
  (print "First text")
  (print "An other text"))
```

Why is only `An other text` displayed when I call `double-print` function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `print` prints to the echo area where you are likely to see the last thing printed only.  However, the output also goes to the `*Messages*`buffer (do `C-h e` to get there fast) where you will see

```
"First text"

"An other text"

"An other text"
```

This is the output of your print expressions followed by the return value of your function (which is the value of the last expression executed and thus "An other text" again).

Comment: If the minibuffer is inactive you can also click into the echo area to display the Messages buffer.

Comment: Ha!  TIL...  Thank you very much.